# What are the security risks of having executable permissions to files in Linux?

Tags: linux, file, unix, permissions

Say that I have in my OS many files with executable permissions, even they are not needed this permission (like .jpg or .txt) - 
What are the security risks of having that? 
The system will be less secure hacking wise?

Thanks

Comment: What would be the reason not to just fix the permissions and not wonder?

Comment: Why would he go through all his files to fix permissions if it does not pose a security thread? And why is it a problem if he wants to learn the background of these security threads?

Comment: I will fix that for the files that I know about, but i still wonder what is the motivation to fix it :)

Comment: This question is more general computing than programming-related and is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow.  [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a more appropriate site for this question.

Comment: @Anthony certainly not. This is essential knowledge for working with web servers and configuring sites.

Comment: It is good practice not to give executable permissions to files that doesn't need it and is known as the [least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) principle. You never know what will new exploits be able to do, what is considered secure today could be dangerous tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

My first thoughts from a security perspective would be..

Having executable permissions on files that should not have them exposes your machine to risks like execution of commands through vulnerabilities such as [null byte injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Periodic_Table_of_Vulnerabilities_-_Null_Byte_Injection) on web servers.

With something like injection attacks the attacker has limited file system access only to files he has permissions to. This includes most file inclusion vulnerabilities which in the end leads to complete system breach when the attacker has the ['everyone' privileges set as executable](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions).